# Google cloud speech to text not giving output for OGG & MP3 files

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to perform speech to text on a bunch of audio files which are over 10 mins long. I don't want to waste storage on the cloud bucket by straight-up uploading wav files on it. So I am using `ffmpeg` to convert the files either to ogg or mp3 like:
`ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -ar 12000 -r 16000 audio.mp3`

`ffmpeg -y -i audio.wav -ar 12000 -r 16000 audio.ogg`

For testing purpose I ran the speech to text service on a dummy wav file and it seemed to work, I got the text as expected. But for some reason it isn't detecting any speech when I use the ogg or mp3 file. I could not give amr files to work either.

My code:

```
def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding="OGG_OPUS", #replace with "LINEAR16" for wav, "OGG_OPUS" for ogg, "AMR" for amr
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code="en-US",
    )
    print("starting operation")
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config=config, audio=audio)
    response = operation.result()
    print(response)
```

I have set up the authentication properly, so that is not a problem.

When I run the speech to text service on the same audio but in ogg or mp3(I just comment out the encoding setting from the config for mp3) format, it gives no response, just prints out a line break and done.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: 1.) Can you run `ffmpeg -i audio.ogg` and check if the encoding is **Vorbis**? If it is Vorbis and not Opus, ffmpeg did not encode this to .ogg properly. You can try using [opus tools](https://opus-codec.org/downloads/) for converting. 2.) Are you using `speech_v1p1beta1` to run the recognition?

Comment: not sure about what version of speech I am running on. and yes it is vorbis

Comment: You can check the manner of your imports in the script (`from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech`) if you imported v1p1beta1 it should support MP3. If not it won't support MP3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Opus or FLAC

- Vorbis (the default audio format for OGG container) is not supported. See [Google Cloud Speech-to-Text: Supported Audio Encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings).
- MP3 encoding is a Beta feature and only available in v1p1beta1. See the [RecognitionConfig reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding) for details.

### FLAC

FLAC is compressed but is lossless. This will result in the best speech-to-text results.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn output.flac
```

### Opus

If file space is very important then use Opus in OGG. It can make small file sizes with excellent quality.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -c:a libopus output.ogg
```